# Impressão dinâmica JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou tentando fazer uma impressão com `JasperReports`, no momento de compilar o relatório recebo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report
>   design not valid :
>      1. The columns and the margins do not fit the page width.
>      2. The background section and the margins do not fit the page height.
>      3. The title section, the page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
>      4. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
>      5. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the last page height.
>      6. The summary  section and the margins do not fit the page height.
>      7. The detail section, the page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
>      8. The noData section and the margins do not fit the page height.  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:241)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:501)
>     at testeimpressao.Impressao.Imprimir(Impressao.java:49)

Segue abaixo o código de teste :

```
JasperDesign report = new JasperDesign();
report.setName("teste");
report.setPageWidth(90);
report.setPageHeight(45);

JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
band.setHeight(45);

JRDesignStaticText text = new JRDesignStaticText();
text.setText("Primeira impressão");
text.setHeight(20);
text.setWidth(60);
text.setX(1);
text.setY(1);
band.addElement(text);

((JRDesignSection)report.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);

JasperReport relatorio = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report); //Aqui ocorre o erro

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, new HashMap<>());
JasperViewer jrviewer = new JasperViewer(print, false);
jrviewer.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o Jaspersoft studio ou iReport para fazer seu relatório? todos os erros são relacionados a tamanho insuficiente da seção.

Comment: @GustavoFragoso, não posso fazer pelo `iReport` porque o formulário será customizado pelo usuário. Ele irá adicionar os campos e os valores de cada campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, parece que o `JasperReports` se perde quando não tem as margens setadas, então setei as margens, outro problema é que ele também não consegue gerar o relatório sem um `DataSource`, pra resolver esse problema passei um `JREmptyDataSource`, o código ficou desta forma:

```
JasperDesign report = new JasperDesign();
report.setName("teste");
report.setPageWidth(90);
report.setPageHeight(45);
report.setBottomMargin(0);
report.setTopMargin(0);
report.setLeftMargin(0);
report.setRightMargin(0);
report.setColumnWidth(89);

JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
band.setHeight(45);

JRDesignStaticText text = new JRDesignStaticText();
text.setText("Primeira impressão");
text.setHeight(20);
text.setWidth(60);
text.setX(1);
text.setY(1);
band.addElement(text);

((JRDesignSection)report.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);

JasperReport relatorio = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, new HashMap<>(), new JREmptyDataSource(1));
print.setPageHeight(report.getPageHeight());
print.setPageWidth(report.getPageWidth());
print.setBottomMargin(report.getBottomMargin());
print.setTopMargin(report.getTopMargin());
print.setLeftMargin(report.getLeftMargin());
print.setRightMargin(report.getRightMargin());

JasperViewer jrviewer = new JasperViewer(print, false);
jrviewer.setVisible(true);
```